# FLUTTER - Futurebuilder keeps returning null after Location Permission

Tags: flutter

**The Problem**

Futurebuilder keeps returning "null" after the user has given permission to acces it's location so it can calculate the distance between 2 locations.

**What I want it to do**

It does give the location when the page is refreshed but I want the distance between 2 objects when the user gives acces to it's location, not when the user refreshed their page.

**The Main Code to run the app**

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'mainlist.dart';




void main() => runApp(MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override

  Widget build(BuildContext context) {

    return new MaterialApp(
      routes: {
        '/second': (context) => mainlist()
      },
      title: "testapp",
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      home: mainlist(),
    );
  }
}
```

**The code where the problem happens - Futurebuilder + getCurrenPosition Future**

```
import 'package:cloud_firestore/cloud_firestore.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

import 'package:async/async.dart';
import 'package:geolocator/geolocator.dart';
import 'package:permission/permission.dart';
import 'mainlist.dart';


class mainlist extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _mainlistpage createState() => _mainlistpage();
}


class _mainlistpage extends State<mainlist> {


  Future<String> getCurrentPosition(DocumentSnapshot document) async{
    Position position = await Geolocator().getCurrentPosition(desiredAccuracy: LocationAccuracy.high);
    double distanceInMeters = await Geolocator().distanceBetween(position.latitude, position.longitude, document['lat'], document['lat']);
    return distanceInMeters.toString();
  }

  var sortBy = "";

  Widget homePage() {
    return StreamBuilder(
      stream: Firestore.instance.collection("Test").orderBy(sortBy).snapshots(),
      builder: (context, snapshot) {
        if (!snapshot.hasData) return Text("Loading");
        return ListView.builder(
            itemCount: snapshot.data.documents.length,
            itemBuilder: (context, index) =>
                _mainListItem(context, snapshot.data.documents[index]));
      },
    );
  }


  @override
  Widget _mainListItem(BuildContext context, DocumentSnapshot document) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Container(
        child: Center(
          child: Column(
              children: <Widget>[
                FutureBuilder(
                    future: getCurrentPosition(document),
                    builder: (BuildContext context,AsyncSnapshot snapshot)  {
                      switch (snapshot.connectionState) {
                        case ConnectionState.none:
                          return Text('none');
                        case ConnectionState.active:
                        case ConnectionState.waiting:
                          return Text('waiting');
                        case ConnectionState.done:
                          if (snapshot.hasError)
                            return Text('Error: ${snapshot.error}');
                          return Text(snapshot.data.toString());

                      }
                      return null; // unreachable
                    }
                ),
              ]
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }

  Widget build(BuildContext context){
    return new Scaffold();
  }
}
```

**What have I tried**

- Using streambuilder
- Messing with the cases in the Futurebuilder
- Reading Stackoverflow
- I have added the permissions in plist and manifest

Comment: did you include the geolocation permissions on the Manifest and the Info.plis?

Comment: @HaironChaviano Yes, I did.
I think because the "mainlist" is fired from the beginning of the app it instantly wants to build the "_mainListItem" and the Futurebuilder has no data untill the user has accepted the permission. 
But on the other hand a Futurebuilder/Streambuilder should reload when it has data right? Now it only loads the data when the user reloads the page. So I was thinking about makeing a seperate page for location permission but I really want to fix it like this.